# Find in double nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like this:

```
{ 
   "_id":ObjectId("5b306824a1eab22e77858c88"),
   "data":{ 
      "Key":[ 
         [ 
            "1529587723",
            "KeyIn"
         ],
         [ 
            "1529587723",
            "Num"
         ],
         [ 
            "1529667745",
            "KeyIn"
         ]
      ]
   },
   "devicecode":"MP1D1XAH@LENOVO"
}
```

my question is how to find all records with "KeyIn"?  I tried

```
db.dataup.find({ "data.key": "KeyIn" })
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double nested [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to find in double nested arrays

```
db.collection.find({
  "data.Key": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": { "$in": ["KeyIn"] }
    }
  }
})
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fXZ7cpa-pQg)

Comment: A perfect piece of query!!